# I want to read a file, remove duplicate lines and write (unique lines) into another file

Tags: haskell, recursion, monads

I am new to haskell and I'm trying to work out this problem. Given 2 files, an input file and output file, I want to read from the input file, remove duplicate lines then write (unique lines) into the output file. I managed to read the file and remove duplicates now I'm having trouble writing to file.

this is my thought process so far:

```
onlyUnique :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
onlyUnique inputFile outputFile = do
-- read input file 
-- remove duplicated lines in file 
-- writes remaining lines into outputFile 
  contents <- readFile inputFile
  let noDups = nub (words contents)
  fileNoDups <- foldr (\x acc -> (writeFile acc x)) outputFile noDups
```

the issue for this solution is the writeFile is the wrong type but I dont know how to go through the list of strings to write to file without using foldr. Recursive? but how do I do that in this case.

**OR**

```
onlyUnique :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
onlyUnique inputFile outputFile = do
-- read input file 
-- remove duplicated lines in file 
-- writes remaining lines into outputFile 
  contents <- readFile inputFile
  let noDups = nub (words contents)
  when (length noDups > 0) $ 
     writeFile outputFile (noDups)
```

Maybe I could create a helper function? But how would that look, I'm just confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said in your question you wanted to remove duplicate **lines**, but in your program, it looks like you're trying to remove duplicate words.

Otherwise, you're on the right track.  Assuming it's **lines** you're interested in, then you can use the *pair* of functions `lines` (which breaks a `String` into a list of lines) and `unlines` (which glues a list of lines back together into a single string) to do what you want.

```
onlyUnique :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
onlyUnique inputFile outputFile = do
  -- read input file 
  contents <- readFile inputFile
  -- remove duplicated lines in file
  let noDups = nub (lines contents)
  -- put lines back together
  let output = unlines noDups
  -- write the result to output file
  writeFile outputFile output
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple oneliner that can be used as program that works with stdin and stdout is:

```
import Data.List (nub)

main :: IO ()
main = interact (unlines . nub . lines)
```

the core of the program is [**`nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) that will produce a list of *unique* elements. The main problem is however that it runs in *(n²)*. We can however work with the [**`removeDuplicates :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Unique-0.4.7.9/docs/Data-List-UniqueUnsorted.html#v:removeDuplicates) of the [**`Unique`** package <sup>[hackage]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Unique), this will perform the filtering process more efficient.

Then we can work with I/O redirection:

```
program < infile > outfile
```